# MySQL Query if else JOIN

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
SELECT * FROM bn_garant_tpl 
JOIN bn_garant_val
WHERE bn_garant_tpl.what_tpl IN (1, 2)
AND bn_garant_tpl.id_tpl = bn_garant_val.id_garant_tpl
ORDER BY ords ASC
```

how to get lines where what_tpl = 1?

problem is next: in table bn_garant_val not exist lines **if what_tpl = 1**. just for **if what_tpl = 2**.

this query return if ID's match

```
AND bn_garant_tpl.id_tpl = bn_garant_val.id_garant_tpl
```

but, in result must be: if **what_tpl = 1** also

Comment: I think you're looking for LEFT OUTER JOIN here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need records from `bn_garant_tpl` even if no such record in `bn_garant_val`, use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM bn_garant_tpl 
LEFT JOIN bn_garant_val ON bn_garant_tpl.id_tpl = bn_garant_val.id_garant_tpl
WHERE bn_garant_tpl.what_tpl IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY ords ASC
```